# AppEngine datastore backup mapreduce failures

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, backup, datastore-admin

I have setup a cron to backup a single kind i.e. only one Entity from the datastore using backup.create. However the backup stalls with Transaction collision errors. What do these errors mean ? I notice these errors occur with very old records in our data store. Is it possible to specify a time-range with the backup.create script ? If so how should the time-range be specified. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note that this old system is being phased out - you'll have a much better time with the new system where that has fixed a lot of existing issues as well as making the system fully managed by Google.

In the past, some client libraries have allowed invalid data to be written, such as invalid UTF-8 strings, however, this is hard for Google to debug on the old system as the error logs happen in the customer's application, rather than our system logs.

You can see how to schedule exports with the new system in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export), and using the CLI is super simple:

`gcloud datastore export --kinds="MyKind" gs://${BUCKET}`